# Cardboard Unity - Black Borders Missing on Stereo image

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk, google-cardboard

Hi I'm using the Cardboard Sdk for unity with Unity 4.6.3
- as recommended in the sdk docs.

Everything works fine and builds and runs to my android phones except for one issue:
there are no black borders around the stereo image
(the edge part of the screen where the grey line and the settings cog icon are)
Bits of the stereo image get smeared around the unrefreshed edges.

This happens on multiple phones so it's not the phone..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in v0.4.5 that should be fixed an upcoming release.  In the meantime, you can also fix it in your current project with this change:

Add a Camera to the scene (anywhere).  Set its properties like this:

- Clear Flags = Solid Color
- Background = black
- Culling Mask = Nothing
- Depth = -100

Comment: +1 This bug is now fixed. The problem can arise, however, when manipulating the CardboardMain object (instead of the head camera inside). If you see this, try recreating the camera